# Offline world map with cities granularity

Tags: android

To teach myself how to work with maps I want to make a following application. I want to see a whole world political map with countries borders. When I press somewhere on a country I want to see the name of this country. The same things I want to do with cities.

The main requirement is that this map should be an **offline** map. Is it possible to find this type of library (such type of map)?

Answer (score 0):

OpenStreetMap offers offline map capability. Whether OSMDroid (OpenStreetMap client library for Android) does or not, I can't say. The Google Maps add-on for Android, notably, does not allow offline maps.